# How to make JEditorpane keep whitespaces

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

In a JEditorPane for formatting purposes i am using Courier New font type. However the whitespaces are being removed as HTML is white-space insensitive. Therefore If I try to print something like this: "1    3 4", it removes the extra spaces and in practice prints "1 3 4". Any thoughts around this?

```
  public  JEditorPane  editorPane;
  editorPane.setEditable(false);
  editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
  // add a HTMLEditorKit to the editor pane
  HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
  editorPane.setEditorKit(kit);
   //...
   //...
  // add some styles to the html
  StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
  styleSheet.addRule("body {color:#0f0; font-family:times; margin: 1px; }");
  styleSheet.addRule("h1 {color:blue;}");
  styleSheet.addRule("h2 {color:#ff0000;}");
  styleSheet.addRule("."+StyleCourierNew+" {font-family:\"Courier New\"; font: 11px monaco; color: black; }");
```

Comment: I got the answer:      st=st.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
sString=sString.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;");
```